# Pop inside procedure does not work as intended

Tags: assembly, stack, x86-16, tasm, dosbox

I have next code in TASM:

```
.MODEL SMALL
.STACK 128
.DATA
    msg        DB 'Message$'
    crlf       DB 0Dh, 0Ah, '$'
.CODE

print_string proc
    pop dx
    mov ah, 09h
    int 21h
    ret
print_string endp

Entry:
    mov ax, @data
    mov ds, ax
    
    push offset msg
    call print_string

    mov ax, 4c00h
    int 21h

END Entry
```

I have a procedure that retrieves a message pointer from the stack for printing, but it prints weird symbols into console.
If I inline my procedure into code like this:

```
push offset msg
pop dx
mov ah, 09h
int 21h
```

it will work correctly and output my message into console.
Can someone explain why popping the same value from stack **inside procedure** results in non-expected behaviour?

Comment: `call` puts a near return address on the stack which `retn` pops back into `ip`. To access parameters pushed onto the stack before a `call` to a function, you can set up `bp` as a frame pointer in the function and address the stack with it. Or `pop` the return address into another register, then do your `pop dx`, then `push` the return address back onto the stack before `retn` runs.

Comment: You can imagine `call X` as a combined `push ip + jmp X`. With this, what do you think the following`pop dx` in print_string will get?

Comment: @ecm can you provide code sample?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### `push`, `call`, `pop`, `ret` all impact the stack

> ```
> push offset msg
> call print_string
> ```

After these 2 instructions have been executed the stack looks like:

```
R, R, M, M, ...          R = Return address (2 bytes)
^                        M = Message pointer (2 bytes)
sp
```

The instruction that runs next is that `pop dx`. The stack will now look like:

```
      M, M, ...
      ^
      sp
```

Contrary to what you intended, the DX register now contains the return address for the `call`/`ret` instructions. That's not a valid pointer to a message and so you see garbage appear on the screen.
And when then the `ret` instruction runs, it will pop off the stack some word that isn't a return address at all.

### Solution 1

Move the return address temporarily away. Next code pops it into AX that we're going to clobber anyway:

```
print_string proc
  pop  ax            ; return address
  pop  dx            ; message pointer (removes the argument from the stack)
  push ax            ; return address
  mov  ah, 09h
  int  21h
  ret
print_string endp
```

### Solution 2

Use a stackframe pointer.

```
print_string proc
  push bp            ; preserving BP
  mov  bp, sp
  mov  dx, [bp+4]    ; message pointer
  mov  ah, 09h
  int  21h
  pop  bp            ; restoring BP
  ret  2             ; remove the argument from the stack
print_string endp
```

Because we want to preserve BP, we used the `push bp` instruction which made the stack look like:

```
B, B, R, R, M, M, ...
^           ^
sp          |
bp          |
<--- +4 --->|
```

We retrieve the message pointer at offset **+4** from the new stackpointer.

### Solution 3

Use a stackframe pointer.

```
print_string proc
  xchg bp, ax        ; preserving BP in the AX register
  mov  bp, sp
  mov  dx, [bp+2]    ; message pointer
  xchg bp, ax        ; restoring BP from the AX register
  mov  ah, 09h
  int  21h
  ret  2             ; remove the argument from the stack
print_string endp
```

Here we preserve BP in the AX register that the code is going to clobber anyway. The stack looks like:

```
R, R, M, M, ...
^     ^
sp    |
bp    |
< +2 >|
```

We retrieve the message pointer at offset **+2** from the new stackpointer.

The last examples used `ret 2` to remove the stacked argument. Alternatively, you could remove the argument once returned to the caller:

```
push offset msg
call print_string
add  sp, 2
```